# Python: data argument can't be an iterator

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to replicate the code that is provided here:
https://github.com/IdoZehori/Credit-Score/blob/master/Credit%20score.ipynb

The function given below fails to run and give error. Can someone help me resolving it

```
def replaceOutlier(data, method = outlierVote, replace='median'):
'''replace: median (auto)
            'minUpper' which is the upper bound of the outlier detection'''
vote = outlierVote(data)
x = pd.DataFrame(zip(data, vote), columns=['annual_income', 'outlier'])
if replace == 'median':
    replace = x.debt.median()
elif replace == 'minUpper':
    replace = min([val for (val, vote) in list(zip(data, vote)) if vote == True])
    if replace < data.mean():
        return 'There are outliers lower than the sample mean'
debtNew = []
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    if x.iloc[i][1] == True:
        debtNew.append(replace)
    else:
        debtNew.append(x.iloc[i][0])

return debtNew
```

Function Call:

```
incomeNew = replaceOutlier(df.annual_income, replace='minUpper')
```

> Error:
>   x = pd.DataFrame(zip(data, vote), columns=['annual_income', 'outlier'])
>   TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator

PS: I understand this has been asked before, but I tried using the techniques however the error still remains

Answer (score 19, accepted):

zip cannot be used directly, you should give the result as a list i.e.:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(data, vote)), columns=['annual_income', 'outlier'])
```

**Edit**  (from [bayethierno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57223112/6655211) answer) :
Since the release 0.24.0, we don't need to generate the list from the `zip` anymore, the following statement is valid :

```
x = pd.DataFrame(zip(data, vote), columns=['annual_income', 'outlier'])
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion , but now a new error: `TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)`

Comment: @user4943236 the list takes only the zip as in my example ?

Answer (score 2):

This actually works in pandas version 0.24.2 without having to use list around zip

Answer (score 1):

write like this

```
coef = DataFrame(list(zip(x.columns,np.transpose(log_model.coef_))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of data type issue, you can first convert it to list and then that list to dataframe. Ex. pd.DataFrame(list(data)) should work.

Answer (score 0):

`zip(list1,list2)` works in Jupyter Notebook, but I find that `list(zip(list1,list2))` is required to work in Python's default compiler.