# How to create a dataframe with multiple lists/arrays in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-profiling

I have many lists which consists of 1d data. like below:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4...]
list2 = ['a','b','c'...]
```

Now, I have to create dataframe like below:

```
df = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']]
```

I need this dataframe so that I can profile each column using pandas_profiling.
Please suggest.

I have tried

```
list1+list2
```

but its giving data like below:

```
list3=[1,2,3,4...'a','b'...]
```

used numpy hpstack too, but not working

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling
import numpy as np

list3 = np.hstack([[list1],[list2]])

array([[1,2,3,4,'a','b','c'..]],dtype='<U5')
```

Comment: Numpy is for number arrays only, use pandas, google some pandas tutorial it should be in the first couple chapters

Comment: `zip` is the correct answer but this is what you could have done in numpy: `np.vstack((list1, list2)).T`

Comment: For lists `+` is a simple join.  With the `hstack` expression you are concatenating (1,n) arrays on the last dimension, producing a (1,2n) array.  `column_stack` will make a (n,2) array, but string dtype.  The python `zip` does a better job of iterleaving the number and string elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [zip function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) described in [the answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196165/joining-two-lists-into-tuples-in-python) to create your nested list.

You should note that you cannot use the zip function directly as it could lead to an [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45388800/python-data-argument-cant-be-an-iterator?rq=1).

The solution would be:

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = ['a','b','c']
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list1,list2)), columns=['list1', 'list2'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way:

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = ['a','b','c','d']
list3 = zip(list1, list2)
df = pd.DataFrame(list3, columns=('list1', 'list2'))
print (df)
```

Output:

```
   list1 list2
0      1     a
1      2     b
2      3     c
3      4     d
```

Comment: This raises an error in my enviroment: TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator

Comment: Sorry for the dealy, I use Python 3.6.3. I edited my answer in case other users experience the same error